# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'

Tags: ios, swift

```
if !isEditing {
    collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.compactMap({ $0 }).forEach {_ in
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: 0, animated: true)
        // Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'
```

Comment: For `at:0` did you mean `at:$0`?

Comment: yes @matt For at:0 did you mean at:$0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `forEach` loop

```
collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.forEach({
    collectionView.deselectItem(at:$0, animated: true)
})
```